# Splitting a hashMap based on values in it's string

Tags: java, string, list, hashmap

How would I go about splitting a hashMap by the values of one string? For example splitting the hashMap table below by key: attribute1 value:"a".

```
    public Map<String, List> table = new HashMap<String, List>();

        String[] attribute1 = {"a", "a", "b", "c", "c"};
        String[] attribute2 = {"car", "car", "car", "train", "bus"};
        String[] attribute3 = {"yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes"};
```

so that it would give:

```
        String[] attribute1 = {"a", "a"};
        String[] attribute2 = {"car", "car"};
        String[] attribute3 = {"yes", "no", };
```

Is there any way I can do this by removing all values of a key with the corresponding value index? From what I've learnt you can't as the values don't have an index in has maps?

Comment: Question is  ambiguous.  what does this.popItem has to do with this problem ?

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't, just included as thats how it's used in my code

Comment: Why do you use the prefix `this`? It's included automagically by the JVM,

Comment: The question is not clear. What is the content of  HashMap as of now ?

Comment: Sorry if I'm being vague, struggling to word the question, I think that's why I'm struggling answer this myself as I don't understand to well.

I basically want to be able to go through one of the lists, pick a value such as "a" and delete all the columns that don't have "a".

Does this make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of finding the correct columns and then loop trough all entries in the table and extract the correct columns:

```
public static Map<String,List> filterMap(Map<String,List> table, String key, String filter) {
   Map<String,List> m = new HashMap<String,List>();
   List l = table.get(key);
   if (l != null) {
      List<Integer> cols = new List<Integer>();
      for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
         if ((filter == null && l.get(i) == null) || (filter != null && filter.equals((String)l.get(i)))) {
            cols.add(new Integer(i));
         }
      }
      // for each entry in table
      //    extract the items saved in cols and add it to m
   }
   return m;
}
```